# Pseudo-Class :hover persists when Max-Height changes

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, mouseevent, pseudo-class

This doesn't happen on Firefox, but it happens on Chrome and IE. What I have is an `<input>` element that generates search suggestions as you type. The suggestions show up in three cases, when the input is active, when your mouse is hovering over the input, or when your mouse is hovering over the search results.

The search results use css-transitions to hide/appear, so I control it with `max-height` being set to 500px (bigger than the list could ever be) and 0.

The problem comes when you click a result. I've created a `click` event (using `jQuery`) so that when you click one of the results, a class is added to the search results to make it hide, and it removes the class after the transition finishes (at this point it should stay hidden because your mouse isn't hovering over it anymore). In Chrome and IE, the list grows again when that class is removed, if you don't move your mouse.

Is there a way to update the browser so the `:hover` pseudo-class goes away?

Here's a modified demo that works nearly the same way: http://jsfiddle.net/zZMcv/3/

Comment: set the list to display:none, then setTimeout to turn it back to display:block after 100ms. While it's hidden the :hover will be dis-engaged, and since it will be tiny when it re-appears, it won't be under the mouse cursor anymore. You might have to disable transition effects to buy enough time for the list to shrink out from under the mouse pointer, a temporary className setting transition-duration to 0 would fit the bill...

Comment: Yeah, just relying on jQuery to change the display attribute works flawlessly, it works with a 0ms delay in Chrome but a 120ms delay in IE. So simply adding these two lines to the `setTimeout(function, 350)` page works:
`v.hide(); setTimeout(function(){v.show();},120);`

Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it :O

Comment: glad it works, but in a rush; i'll let someone ambitious grab the answer first-come, anyone?

Comment: Just put it in later :P I don't mind marking it in two days or whenever. But I'm not going to reward someone for something they didn't think of, unless it's an alternative answer that works better.

Comment: np, im back and posted a solution (i thinks)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can modify the js code to show and hide the list so as to dodge the :hover

```
function addResults() {
    $(this).parents('.input-field-label-set-2-column').next().empty().append($('<b>').text($(this).text()));
    var v = $(this).parent();
    pendSearch.call(v.prev().val(this.innerHTML)[0]);
    v.addClass("js-hide");

    v.hide(); 
    setTimeout(function(){v.show();},120);

    setTimeout(function () { v.removeClass("js-hide"); }, 350);
}
```

or, you can likely simply modify the .js-hide class so that it sets display:none; transition-duration:0;

or, an aside, in good browsers, you can use the list attrib on an input in conjunction with a datalist element to avoid this any many more minor snags when doing gui suggestions...